# Whether to strike?

Tags: graduate-school, teaching, teaching-assistant

I'm a graduate student teaching assistant; I run discussion sections. Our department has just initiated a strike. I'm half way through the last semester of my PhD. Do I show up and "work" and get paid (my students may not show up anyway), or do I participate in the strike that I don't care about and lose that hourly pay? It's emphasized there's no negative effects from participating in the strike, but I'm worried more about the potential effects of not participating (of deciding to show up for work).

Comment: Are you under the same contract as the full time faculty on strike?

Comment: This has too many un-specified variables to get a meaningful answer. The law in the given location may be a factor along with many other considerations.

Comment: You have to check as if you are not on the same contract as full-time, to be with students you may need the full-time faculty present on-site... so even if you are there you may not be permitted to work with the students...

Comment: Or you could try not being a scab

Comment: @AzorAhai "SCAB" really - that depends on the contract... and I hope you would understand that...

Comment: @AzorAhai You have no idea about OP's predicaments, financial and legal situation for making such a comment. And what if - even if probably not relevant in this case - OP simply disagrees with the cause of the strikers? Your derogatory comment is totally inappropriate and quite surprising, coming from someone with such high reputation.

Comment: It is only grad student workers striking. I don't know anything about contract specifics. I run my own discussion sections 2 days a week (which supplement their lectures they go to separately with the professor 3 days a week).

Comment: @CaptainEmacs The OP did choose to attend a program where the grad students were unionized. Crossing lines just because you personally aren't affected by the contract demands is at the very least a selfish and crappy thing to do to fellow grad students. Especially since the OP has almost certainly been benefitting from union bargaining up to this point.

Comment: @Nights The fact that you're asking this question here is a clue that you already know what the right thing to do is.

Comment: @ElizabethHenning You seem to posit that OP chose the program based on grad students being unionised. You fail to take into account that OP may have had no interest in politics. It is a feature of modern social constructions that people may end up profiting from social contracts that they themselves would not have supported. Even so far as to people voting for the precise party that opposes the support that they themselves receive. I may sympathise with the causes of a particular union activity, but I consider the "ganging up" attitude sometimes exhibited to enforce support very questionable.

Comment: @CaptainEmacs No, I'm positing that the OP knew that they were choosing a program with a union. I'm also positing that if you sign up for something, you sign up for the parts you don't like too, along with whatever the ethical consequences are.

Comment: I really doubt that I would have known if a specific university had a union of grad students or not before going there - it really wasn’t something I would have looked into at the time. Given the grad students I knew then and know now, the majority would be at best apolitical, and any decision to strike was made by a small, albeit active, minority.

Comment: @ElizabethHenning You are positing that the OP knew that there is a program with a union? There is no evidence for that in the OP's question. Even if it were, where is it implied that participation is obligatory? Is this like a religious college where only practicing members of the religion are accepted to their programs? One would have thought that the concept of obligatory membership in a political organisation or at very least compliance with their next activism as precondition to not being socially ostracised should have died with the demise of the Soviet bloc in the '90s.

Comment: Oh, for goodness' sake. You all do know how unions work, right?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Our department has just initiated a strike.

Does this mean the graduate students are striking or the department, including tenured faculty, are striking?

> I show up and "work" and get paid (my students may not show up anyway), or do I participate in the strike that I don't care about and lose that hourly pay?

There are more than two options here.  There are two things about academic (in the U.S. and most of Europe) that would make me lean towards striking

1) Academic circles tend to be small, and there is a high likelihood you'll run into your fellow grad students down the road.

2) Universities tend to be very liberal, which in the U.S. means supporting unions.  Future bosses are likely to side with the strikers.

### **Be the only one, or one of the few, to show up for work**

**Pros** - You'll get paid, and if the faculty are still working, you'll probably get one-on-one attention.

**Cons** - All your co-workers know you as [a scab](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strikebreaker).  When things return to normal you'll be seen as "aiding the enemy" by many of your fellow grad students.

### **Join the other grad students on the picket line (assuming you are picketing)**

**Pros** - You'll be seen as an ally by your fellow grad students.

**Cons** - You don't get paid and you have no time to write your thesis.

### **Stay home and write your thesis**

**Pros** - You continue working on your thesis.  You're going along with the strike, and will probably be seen favorably by your fellow grad students when the strike ends.

**Cons** - You don't get paid.

### **Find part-time shift work to supplement income**

**Pros** - You get paid some money and have some time to work on your thesis. 
 You're going along with the strike, and will probably be seen favorably by your fellow grad students when the strike ends.

**Cons** - The job will need to be very temporary.

Comment: Working at home isn't "going along with the strike", unless the strike is specifically restricted to certain kinds of work (e.g., teaching) and the work being done at home is not of that kind (e.g., thesis writing).

Comment: It is only grad student workers striking. I don't know anything about contract specifics. I run my own discussion sections 2 days a week (which supplement their lectures they go to separately with the professor 3 days a week).